# Why do like poles of a weak and strong magnet attract each other when brought close to each other at very high speeds?

Tags: electromagnetism

So, I understand that the magnetic domains in the weak magnet are realigning when exposed to the strong magnet. But what is it with the speed, like how does speed come into the picture?

P.S. This question was asked to me by a kid of 7th standard. He found this thing in his physical science textbook. I could explain to him that it has something to do with realigning of magnetic domains, but I really don't know, what role does speed play.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do two like poles stick together when one magnet is stronger than the other?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454952/why-do-two-like-poles-stick-together-when-one-magnet-is-stronger-than-the-other)

Comment: Sadly that question has only one, too short answer.

Comment: @stafusa That answer explains the realignment of magnetic domains in the weak magnet, which I understand. Weak magnets are usually soft iron which has small remnant magnetization, thus loses its magnetic property quickly. While the hard iron (permanent magnets) have large remnant magnetization (can be understood from hysteresis loop). But has it got anything to do with velocity, never heard of such a thing!

Comment: Lekha, are you sure it really has to do with velocity? I'd guess that trula's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/572867/75633) can be correct in that the speed only helps overcoming the repulsion to bring the magnets close enough together.

Comment: Stafusa, I have not checked the exact words from the book, it was verbal discussion. But even I felt that Trula's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed is necessary just so that the two magnets get close enough together, if you do it slowly the repulsive force would not allow it to get close enough for realignment to take place. Instead of high speed you can move slowly, if you exert enough force.

Comment: I changed the wording of your post, because I think it was probably the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: thank you status